# How to make JCheckBox from text file data

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, text-files

I have an JTable which is displaying data from a file. I want to have in this JTable a column of checkboxes. I know I have to override getColumnClass method to return Boolean.class. I'm doing this this way:

```
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel = tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, col.length){
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colIndex) {
        if (colIndex == 6)
                return java.lang.Boolean.class;
        else
        return java.lang.Object.class;
    }
};
```

As I said data for JTable is stored in txt file. I know how to read it to display all things in table, but I don't know how I can make set checkboxes to display values (true, false). 
My file looks like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaa|cw27729|604208652|16/02/2015|description|cost|Here i want data for checkboxes|
sdfsdf|sdfdsf|sdfsf|16/02/2015|description|cost|Here i want data for checkboxes|
```

So if there is no text in last column in file table is displaying empty checkboxes, which is fine. But what should my file look like if i want checkbox to be checked? I tried Boolean.TRUE, true, or differnt wierd things and I always get a lot of errors.

I think it's beacuse when I'm reading a file all data are in String format and there should be Boolean.Class in column which is supposed to display checkboxes.

Can anyone kind help me?
Sorry if my English is bad, it is not my native language.

EDIT: Here's the code of the class (sorry if it's messy)(I add it here cuz I don't know how can I do it other way)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StartFrameV2 extends JFrame {
public StartFrameV2() {
    setTitle("Dane pojazdów/części");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    final JButton button = new JButton("Zamknij");
    southPanel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    final JButton addButton = new JButton("Dodaj element");
    northPanel.add(addButton);
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (dialog == null)
                dialog = new AddFrame(StartFrameV2.this);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    final JButton searchButton = new JButton("Szukaj");
    northPanel.add(searchButton);

    add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JTable contentTable = new JTable();

    tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
    contentTable.setModel(tableModel);
    contentTable.getColumn("Marka").setPreferredWidth(100);
    contentTable.getColumn("Numer telefonu").setPreferredWidth(100);
    contentTable.getColumn("Numer rejestracyjny").setPreferredWidth(100);
    contentTable.getColumn("Data przyjęcia").setPreferredWidth(70);
    contentTable.getColumn("Opis").setPreferredWidth(300);
    contentTable.getColumn("F/P").setPreferredWidth(50);
    contentTable.getColumn("Koszt").setPreferredWidth(70);
    readFile(tableModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentTable);
    add(scrollPane);

}

public void readFile(DefaultTableModel tableModel){
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            tableModel.addRow(line.split("\\|"));
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int lineCounter() {                          // How many lines there is in a file
    int linenumber = 0;
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

        while(lnr.readLine() != null){
            linenumber++;
        }
        System.out.println(linenumber);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return linenumber;
}


private Object[] col = {"Marka", "Numer rejestracyjny", "Numer telefonu", "Data przyjęcia", "Opis", "F/P", "Koszt"};
private DefaultTableModel tableModel = tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, col.length){
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colIndex) {
        if (colIndex == 6)
                return java.lang.Boolean.class;
        else
        return java.lang.Object.class;
    }
};

    private final static File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Mateusz\\Desktop\\test.txt");

    private int WIDTH = 800;
    private int HEIGHT = 300;
    private AddFrame dialog;

}
```

I think I have to change readFile() method to do anything here...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Hard code some data to replace the file.

Comment: *"file all data are in String format and there should be Boolean."*  See [`Boolean.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)..

Comment: I edited post. There is my code.

Comment: How do you expect us to run the code without.. `new File("C:\\Users\\Mateusz\\Desktop\\test.txt");`?  That's why I advised you to **hard-code** some data to replace the file!  Oh, and then there is `private AddFrame dialog;`..

Answer (score 0):

String to boolean-converter:
assuming that string "42" means true, any other means false:

```
private static boolean s2b(String test) {
    return test.equals("42");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(s2b("42")); //true
    System.out.println(s2b("88")); //false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add "true" or "false" into the file (without quotes).

You can then use `Boolean.parseBoolean` to convert the `String` to a `boolean` value

You can do this either when you load the data or when `getValueAt` is called for the column

Another option would be to apply a custom cell render. With this renderer you would be to convert what ever value you have in the cell to a boolean value and update the state of the cell render (which should be based on `JCheckBox`), but you'd have to do the same thing for the cell editor...